# Some questions on Apache Aurora

Tags: mesos, marathon, apache-aurora

I have been comparing Marathon with Aurora.

Marathon:

- Easy to use
- Light weight
- More active to add new features

Aurora:

- More feature sets, and more flexible object configurations
- Heavy and difficult to use
- More conservative adding new features

Right now, we can not decide which one to use. Here are several questions hope can be answered by someone:

1. How to handle group of tasks in Aurora? Grouping is supported in Marathon, a group of tasks can be managed together, but I cannot find grouping in Aurora.
2. How to config environment variables for processes/tasks in Aurora?
3. How to add event handler for status updates in Aurora? We would like to implement customized alerting. It is possible in Marathon.

Answer (score 1):

Aurora is a great scheduler and is very solid, especially the templating and it's DSL makes aurora very powerful. I had a few gists ready and docs as an example but i can only post 2 url's here.

1. Aurora supports processes, tasks and jobs. Usually when we wish to have tasks executed on the same host we place these in processes, its also possible to combine or concat tasks. Aurora has excellent support for executing processes, they can be done sequential or parallel.

An example can be found here: 
http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/reference/configuration-tutorial/#sequentialtask-running-processes-in-parallel-or-sequentially

Another option is to run tasks combined.
{{replace with the aurora website}}/documentation/latest/reference/configuration-tutorial/#combining-tasks)

2. This is recently added to the documentation on how to add environment variables. For now you can check this link until its published on the website: 
   https://github.com/apache/aurora/blob/2a8c667ec1b48900530975169f132d9deb098399/docs/reference/configuration-tutorial.md#getting-environment-variables-into-the-sandbox
3. Currently to my knowledge there are no event handlers for status updates, perhaps someone else can answer this question better than me. An option that comes close:
   What you can do is add a finalizing task that sends out an alert or triggers an event. This task will run after all processes are stopped, you can run multiple finalizing tasks. Do not have an direct link, but if you search for final on this page you find more: 
   {{replace with the aurora website}}/documentation/latest/reference/configuration/

And just saw this was a year ago, but perhaps someone else will be happy with this.